# Wrong headers when trying to GET image

Tags: android, spring, resttemplate, robospice

I am trying to fetch an image using Spring for Android and Robospice. I have my SpiceService set up with a createRestTemplate method as per the various samples on GitHub and this is were I set my headers. I also set Gson, Form and StringHttp message converters.

This setup works fine when only getting plain JSON, but when I try to fetch an image the headers get set to some default values, meaning I loose my Auth header and the request fails.

I have also tried to set a new resttemplate inside the Request itself.

What am I missing here.

EDIT:
The Request used for downloading a json:

```
public class GetMeRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<User> {
public static final String TAG = "GetMeRequest";

public GetMeRequest() {
    super(User.class);
}

@Override
public User loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    Log.d( TAG, "================loading from network" );
    ResponseObject response = getRestTemplate().getForObject( ApiCalls.USERS_ME_URI, ResponseObject.class );

    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
    if(!response.data.users.isEmpty() && response.data.users != null){
        return response.data.users.get(0);
    }
    return null;
   }
}
```

The image request looks like this and is basically a [BigBinaryRequest](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org%24maven2@com.octo.android.robospice%24robospice@1.0.0@com%24octo%24android%24robospice%24request%24simple%24BigBinaryRequest.java):

```
public class ImageRequest extends SpringAndroidSpiceRequest<InputStream> {
protected String url;
protected File cacheFile;
protected String auth;

public ImageRequest(String url, File cacheFile, String auth) {
    super(InputStream.class);
    this.url = url;
    this.cacheFile = cacheFile;
    this.auth = auth;
}

@Override
public InputStream loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
    try {
        java.io.InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        // touch
        cacheFile.setLastModified(System.currentTimeMillis());

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
        Utils.copyLargeFile(is, fileOutputStream);
        return new FileInputStream(cacheFile);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create image URL", e);
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to download image", e);
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Now looking at the two I see that i use the getRestTemplate method wich probably fetches the RestTemplate with my headers. This is probably the problem, but can someone please give me a hint on how to procede?

Edit2:
And the createRestTemplate method from my SpiceService

```
@Override
public RestTemplate createRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate() {
        @Override
        protected ClientHttpRequest createRequest( URI url, HttpMethod method ) throws IOException {
            ClientHttpRequest request = super.createRequest( url, method );
            HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
            headers.setAcceptEncoding( ContentCodingType.GZIP );
            headers.set("Accept", "*/*");
            headers.setUserAgent(P1Application.USER_AGENT);
            headers.setContentType(new MediaType("application","json"));
            headers.set("Authorization", ((P1Application)getApplication()).getAuth());
            return request;
        }
    };


    // set timeout for requests
    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = restTemplate.getRequestFactory();
    if ( factory instanceof HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory ) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory = (HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
        advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout( TIMEOUT );
        advancedFactory.setReadTimeout( TIMEOUT );
    } else if ( factory instanceof SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory ) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory advancedFactory = (SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory) factory;
        advancedFactory.setConnectTimeout( TIMEOUT );
        advancedFactory.setReadTimeout( TIMEOUT );
    }

    GsonHttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
    FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    final List< HttpMessageConverter< ? >> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();

    listHttpMessageConverters.add( jsonConverter );
    listHttpMessageConverters.add( formHttpMessageConverter );
    listHttpMessageConverters.add( stringHttpMessageConverter );
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters( listHttpMessageConverters );
    return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: I don't know. What /we/ are missing is code.

Comment: @Marcel silly me... I just assumed that everyone here is psychic. Added code for the two Request classes. The first one works as expected with correct headers and the second is sent with a default set of headers

Comment: There are a few things about your code that I don't understand (don't need to either, I guess). However, the big question is why you don't use the `RestTemplate` to retrieve your images? That works just fine: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/ -> "Retrieving the photos" or https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7357

Comment: @Marcel That's because I'm new at this game and just followed the RoboSpice examples. =) You are correct. Using RestTemplate  as per the sources you provided made it set my headers as expected. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should use `RestTemplate` also to retrieve images: http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate/ -> "Retrieving the photos".